# Is there a way to vectorise over ragged arrays in polars

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

I have a column with lists of different length like below and want to make a parallel np.diff on each of the independent arrays.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
ragged_arrays = [np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.choice(range(10))) for _ in range(5)]

df = pl.DataFrame({'values':ragged_arrays})
df

shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────────────┐
│ values            │
│ ---               │
│ object            │
╞═══════════════════╡
│ [0 3 3 7 9]       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [5 2 4]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [6 8 8 1 6 7 7]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1 5 9 8 9 4 3 0] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [5 0 2]           │
└───────────────────┘
```

I have tried to simply apply np.diff like this:

```
df.select([
    np.diff(pl.col("values"))
])
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional
```

It looks like this type of vectorisation is not supported at the moment, but is there any workaround to achieve the same thing with polars? I want to avoid having to group arrays by length before running this.

Comment: Numpy does not (really) supports jagged arrays (and will not any time soon). The usual solution is to use (slow) loops. Alternatively, there are better data structure to support them efficiently but they are not directly compatible with any dataframe packages and thus this require an additional conversion step which is certainly slower than doing a basic diff in your case. There is also ways to improve the speed of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you create a `DataFrame` of type `Object` this is almost never what you want. Polars does not know what to do with this dtype.

I adapted your example a bit to create a ragged array of dtype `pl.List`.

There is a special namespace `expression.arr` that gives you access to expressions especially designed for `Series` the `List` dtype.

As of `polars>=0.13.8` this includes `arr.diff`.

```py
np.random.seed(0)
ragged_arrays = [pl.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.choice(range(10)))) for _ in range(5)]

(pl.DataFrame({
    "values": ragged_arrays
}).with_columns([
    pl.col("values").arr.diff().alias("values_diff")
]))
```

This yields

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ values        ┆ values_diff       │
│ ---           ┆ ---               │
│ list [i64]    ┆ list [i64]        │
╞═══════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ [0, 3, ... 9] ┆ [null, 3, ... 2]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [5, 2, 4]     ┆ [null, -3, 2]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [6, 8, ... 7] ┆ [null, 2, ... 0]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [1, 5, ... 0] ┆ [null, 4, ... -3] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [5, 0, 2]     ┆ [null, -5, 2]     │
└───────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! It looks somewhat analogous to the .str accessor in pandas, so it feels like it makes sense.